# Magento 2 coding standards : phpcs --standard=PHPCompatibility github action to check extension code

Tags: coding-standards, phpcs

Today I came across a really useful set of tools. Magento 2 github actions:

https://github.com/extdn/github-actions-m2

Which means you can run a github action workflows to scan your code for Magento coding standard. For example:

https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_Webp2/blob/master/.github/workflows/extdn-static-tests.yml

.github/workflows/extdn-static-tests.yml

```yml
name: ExtDN Static Tests
on: [push]

jobs:
  static:
    name: Static Code Analysis
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: extdn/github-actions-m2/magento-coding-standard@master
```

Pretty amazing. However I would also like a github action to scan Magento 2 extension using PHPCompatibility standard for a defined set of php versions.

For example locally the command would look a bit like this

`vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/bin/phpcs --standard=PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 7.0-7.4 --colors --warning-severity=0 --report=full,summary --extensions=php,phtml ./`

I've had a few goes but I can't get the syntax right.

Has someone somewhere got a github action which does the above?

Comment: Do you need a github action or do you just want to run PHPCompatibility check inside githubs workflow?

Comment: @sv3n extdn github action like this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DominicWatts/AddBodyClass/main/.github/workflows/phpcompatibility.yml - I can't remember how I left this I think I got it working with assistance their side and a merge request which created the required docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/extdn/php-compatibility-action

Answer (score 1):

Late answer ...

I've played around with github actions and PHPCompatibility check these days.

If you use **composer** for you project, you dont need a docker image.

###### Add (dev) dependencies:

- `squizlabs/php_codesniffer`
- `phpcompatibility/php-compatibility`

###### (Auto-)Install PHPCompatibility (and other) rules

- `dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer`

###### Add Workflow file to .github/workflows with ...

```
    ...
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: PHPCodeSniffer
        run: php vendor/bin/phpcs <your-options>
```

[E.g.](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/actions/runs/3568945789/jobs/5998386406) ...

Comment: I finally remembered how it all works. I posted another answer.

Comment: Also I think the reason I didn't go this route is that you have to remember to exclude scanning vendor folder

Answer (score 1):

The follow up to this is that I got a couple of merge requests accepted and it can be achieved with following github action

```
name: ExtDN PHP Compatibility
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  static:
    name: ExtDN PHP Compatibility
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: extdn/github-actions-m2/php-compatibility/8.1@master
```

Can toggle version to match PHP version you are working with

Answer (score 0):

The default coding standard used by PHP_CodeSniffer is the PEAR coding standard. To check a file against the PEAR coding standard, simply specify the file's location:

> $ phpcs /path/to/code/myfile.php

Or if you wish to check an entire directory you can specify the directory location instead of a file.

> $ phpcs /path/to/code-directory

If you wish to check your code against the PSR-12 coding standard, use the --standard command-line argument:

> $ phpcs --standard=PSR12 /path/to/code-directory

If PHP_CodeSniffer finds any coding standard errors, a report will be shown after running the command.

Full usage information and example reports are available on the usage page

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please check again. I'm looking for a github action that checks code against the PHPCompatibility standard.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a pull request to add the functionality

https://github.com/extdn/github-actions-m2/commit/fb9e7461a01743a49e3466eda0dc481d7d61c737

Just waiting on someone their side to build docker image so I can start to use it in github actions